# What's wrong with this trimmomatic PE command?

Tags: trim, nextflow

I'm creating a custom pipline for learning nextflow, and I want to use trimmomatic PE. But I get error from the process, but due to terrible trimmomatic error messages it can be known nothing, so I checked if all files are in nextfow working directory, if there are missspelings, if main.nf is good etc. And I'm 95% sure that it is trimmomatic problem not the nextflow's or docker's.
From .command.sh I recive a it like this:

`trimmomatic PE -phred33 Paris_stat1_R1_001.fastq Paris_stat1_R2_001.fastq stat1_1_trimmed.fastq stat1_drop1.fastq stat1_2_trimmed.fastq stat1_drop2.fastq ILLUMINACLIP:adaptors.fasta:2:30:10 LEADING:3 TRAILING:3 SLIDINGWINDOW:4:15 MINLEN:36`

Is something wrong with this command build for trimmomatic?

Comment: You can run docker container, mount working directory for this process as volume, so you have all the input files exact same way as NF has (e.g. `docker run --rm -ti -v <workdir-for-trimmomatic-process>:/data <your-trimmomatic-container>:<tag> bash`)  and try to run the trimmomatic command (`cd /data` and then your command). Thats what I usually do trying to figure out where the problem is.

Comment: without the error messages and at least the `nextflow` code `process trimmomatic_executing {}` it is hard to debug.